# Does gzip has an extract method like tarfile.extract?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gzip

For example tarfile.extractall(path) extracts the contents to specified direcotry. Similarly does gzip has any extract method to get the gzip member (contains only one file as per standards) to the specified directory or is there any workaround?

Edit: I don't want to read the complete file in to the memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as gzip is only a compression format and not an archive one, there are no extract methods in the `gzip` module nor in the `gzip.GzipFile` class. But you have no reason to load the complete file in memory, you can just copy it in chunks. The manual gives an example on how to compress a file, it can be easily adapted to uncompress it:

```
import gzip
import shutil
with open('/home/joe/file.txt', 'wb') as f_out:
    with gzip.open('/home/joe/file.txt.gz', 'rb') as f_in:
        shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)
```

`shutil.copyfileobj` is meant to process copies in chunks.